# user type(admin,user)login application from java swing with mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Its working fine with correct user and password,but when i use wrong user and password, it does not work.if and else-if working but else statement is not working.

here is my code :

```
            String user = textField.getText().trim();
            String pwd = new String(passwordField.getPassword()).trim();
            String type = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                String sql = "select * from userauthentication where username=? and password=? and type=?";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, user);
                ps.setString(2, pwd);
                ps.setString(3, type);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String uname = rs.getString("username");
                    String pass = rs.getString("password");
                    if ((user.equals(uname) && pwd.equals(pass))) {
                        if (type.equals(Admin_Type)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    " This is from admin message.");
                            // rs.close();
                        } else if (type.equals(User_Type)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "This is from user message.");
                            // rs.close();
                        }

                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "No user found!.");

                        }

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Something going wrong.please try again.");

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Comment: *"is not working."* How it's not working?

Comment: What happens if no results are found matching your query?

Answer (score 1):

Add below condition before the while loop

```
if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    //show error message here.
    System.out.println("No data"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix is use an if statement instead of a while loop in order to check that you retreive a valid user.

Consider that the resultset probably wont retrive any data so in that case the statements after the while loop will not be executed.

Here is an alternative

```
if (rs.next()) {

    if (type.equals(Admin_Type)) {
        message = " This is from admin message.";  
    } else if (type.equals(User_Type)) {
        message = " This is from user message.";
    } else {
        message = "Invalid Type user!.";
    }

} else {
    message ="Something going wrong.please try again.";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
```

Also consider to use another authentication method based on frameworks, avoid to create your own authentication method.  This sample is good for educational prupose to practice how to read fields from database using a ResultSet and how to display message throught JOptionPane.

Regards